# Updating value of cell in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to add an entire row content in JTable. But for some reason, the contents are not being added.

Adding columns into table

```
int col_c = 0;
            String qq_temp = String.format ("SELECT %s FROM `%s`;", req_cols, table_name);
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement (qq_temp);
            rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rset.getMetaData();
            try {
                while (col_c != rsmd.getColumnCount ()) {
                    TableColumn toAdd = new TableColumn();
                    toAdd.setHeaderValue(rsmd.getColumnName(col_c+1));
                    toAdd.setIdentifier(rsmd.getColumnName(col_c+1));
                    jTable1.addColumn (toAdd);
                    System.out.println (col_c + " | " + rsmd.getColumnName (col_c+1));
                    col_c ++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace (); }
```

Fetching row data and combining them to send:

```
                String query2 = String.format ("SELECT `Name`, %s FROM `%s`;", req_cols, table_name);
            System.out.println (query2);
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement (query2);
            rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            
            int j = 1, g = 0, row_count = 0;
            System.out.println (rsmd.getColumnCount());
            try {
            while (rset.next()) {
                
                names.add (rset.getString (1));
                System.out.println (rset.getString(1));
                char[] ssts = new char[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
                
                for (int i = 2; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i ++) {
                    
                    ssts[i-2] = rset.getString(i).charAt(0);
                    System.out.println (row_count + " | " + i + " | " + ssts[i-2]);
                    //System.out.println (row_count + " | " + i + " | " + jTable1.getValueAt (row_count, i));
                }
                _addRow (names.get(g), ssts);
                System.out.println (ssts);
                row_count ++;
                g++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println (e); e.printStackTrace (); }
            //System.out.println ("Req cols: " + req_cols);
            //System.out.println ("Table name: " + tname);
            conn.close ();
    }
    
            
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println (e); }
```

My _addRow function:

```
private void _addRow (String dname, char[] sts) {
    DefaultTableModel jm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel ();
    jm.addRow (new Object[]{dname, sts});
    jm.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

The output table looks like this:
![OUTPUT TABLE] (https://hosting.photobucket.com/images/i/chinnu1645/t1.png?width=450&height=278&crop=fill)

But the values of ssts in 2nd code snippet is perfectly working, but it is not being added in the table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](help/mcve).
Please read (and follow) the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Why are you messing about with adding the columns manually.  Set up the `TableModel` return that information itself